# Меню Navigation Drawer перекрывает активные элементы под собой

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation-drawer

Обнаружил, что боковое меню даже будучи закрытым перекрывает все интерактивные элементы, находящиеся под ним, за исключением единственной кнопки, которая наоборот всегда держится поверх, не смотря ни на что. Как можно это пофиксить? Возможно есть какой-нибудь атрибут или костыль с включением-отключением NavigationView.

Разметка основного экрана:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    layout="@layout/layout_background"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<include
    layout="@layout/drawer_menu"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Разметка drawer_, которая добавляется поверх основного окна:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">




<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_mainmenu"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_mainmenu">

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Скорее всего у вас в разметке что-то не то. Покажите её. Текстом только, не фоткой или скриншотом. Однако скриншот экрана с демонстрацией проблемы может пригодиться.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб обновил

Comment: Вам не надо одну разметку поверх другой располагать (к тому же не ясно как вы это сделали). Вам нужно основную разметку поместить внутрь DrawerLayout, сразу после NavigationView